# What is the best way to create a patch for openssl-1.0.2l missing file inside buildroot?

Tags: openssl, buildroot

While building the openssl in the buildroot, I get the following error.

```
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `../../include/openssl/idea.h', needed by `e_idea.o'.  Stop.
```

The solution is

```
 cp crypto/idea/idea.h include/openss
```

The question is how can I make a patch of this in buildroot?
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Errors like this normally occur due to a failure to run "make depend".

Comment: Cannot reproduce on buildroot master. What's your Buildroot version? Can you post your (def)config? Did you try `make clean; make`? -- And be aware the best support channels for Buildroot problems are IRC, mailing list and the bug tracker (see https://buildroot.org/support.html), you'll have better replies there.